# How do we import C code outputs to be used in matlab for visualisation

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

i have a C code that finds the solution of a function using the methode of bisection and Newton Raphson, and i want to compare the results using graphs ( i am asked to do so in matlab as it's a school project ), but i have no idea how.

here's my code :
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float F0 (float V)
{
float J0 = 1e-15;
float n = 0.68;
float V0 = 0.025;
int E = 1;
int R = 100;
    return (E-V-R*J0*(exp(n*V/V0)-1));
}

float F1 (float V)
{
float J0 = 1e-15;
float n = 0.68;
float V0 = 0.025;
int E = 1;
int R = 100;
    return (-1-n*R*J0/V0*exp(n*V/V0));
}
void Dichotomie (float *V, float a, float b, int *itr)
{
    *V=(a+b)/2;
    ++(*itr);
    printf("Iteration no. %3d V = %7.5f\n", *itr, *V);

}

void Newton(int itr, int maxmitr, float h, float V0, float V1, float err)
{

    for (itr=1; itr<=maxmitr; itr++)
    {
        h=F0(V0)/F1(V0);
        V1=V0-h;
        printf("Iteration no. %3d, V = %9.6f\n", itr, V1);
        if (fabs(h) < 2*err)
        {
            printf("After %3d iterations, root = %8.6f\n", itr, V1);
            return;
        }
        V0=V1;
    }
    printf(" The required solution does not converge or iterations are insufficient\n");
    return;
}

int main ()
{
    float J0 = 1e-15;
    float n = 0.68;
    float V0 = 0.025;
    int E = 1;
    int R = 100;
    int itr = 0, maxmitr;
    float V, a, b, err, V1;
    float h;

    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    err = 0.000001;
    maxmitr = 100;
    Newton(itr, maxmitr,h,V0,V1,err);

    Dichotomie (&V, a, b, &itr);
    do
    {
        if (F0(a)*F0(V) < 0)
            b=V;
        else
            a=V;
        Dichotomie (&V1, a, b, &itr);
        if (fabs(V1-V) < 2*err)
        {
            printf("After %d iterations, root = %6.6f\n", itr, V1);
            return 0;
        }
        V=V1;
    }
    while (itr < maxmitr);
    printf("The solution does not converge or iterations are not sufficient");

        

    


    return 1;
}
```

`

I read some documentations about this in the Matlab website, and i found that there is a function block in Simulink to be used, but i have no idea how Simulink works.

Comment: What mean : " compare the results using graphs " ?

Comment: You should definitely run your code through auto-format ot beautifier.

Comment: You can write values to a text file, adding `data=[` before the first value and `];` after the last. This will now be a MATLAB script that you can run in MATLAB. You can also write to a CSV file, which is really easy, and import that into MATLAB with one of the standard data import utilities.